# Biztalk Ordered Delivery direct bound to multiple ports

Tags: biztalk, ordered-delivery

another ordered delivery problem.

We have an orchestration which is bound to a send port which has ordered delivery true. Another send port also picks up these messages through filtering, this port also has ordered delivery.

Now for some reason when there are multiple ports using the message and one of these is directly port binded only one of the ports is being used. I mean that not both ports give an output.

If i unenlist one of the ports it's always outputted, this works in both ways.

We used to have this with 2 ports which both used filters instead, this worked but we had to change one to a direct port, the problem occured since then. Also the choice of ports for BizTalk is pretty random, because on our server it for example chooses port A and when I recreate the same problem on my local machine it for example choses port B.

It's kind of a weird problem and we have no idea what could be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this a bug in BizTalk Messaging engine worker thread, for it doesnot execute all ordered delivery Send Ports at the same time running under the same host. At max, it runs only two ordered delivery Send port, but if you have four to five ordered delivery Send ports, then only at max two send port execute at one time. To make all the ordered delivery send port works at a time, you need to put them under different host

Answer (score 1):

David Hall: I recreated this on my BizTalk 2010 box and never faced the problem you are mentioning! You have to set `ALLOW MULTIPLE RESPONSES` to `True`. It is under the HOSTS tab in BizTalk settings dashboard.

So, I've got 4 send ports. Each has Ordered Delivery turned `ON`. All send ports are on same subscription, i.e. BTS.ReceivePortName. I have an MLLP receive location for receiving the message into the Biztalk box.

Test Case: Does BizTalk maintain order ?

I sent 5 diff messages in this order 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5. All 4 send ports sent the message out in the same order 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5.

Result; YES it does.

Forgot to mention. Everything is running under one default host of BizTalkServerApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add the filter to a Port Group instead, and have all the other properties in the specific ports?